# How does WCF's ClientBase<TChannel> handle TCP connections when Disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets, tcp

A while ago I came across an interesting article explaining that putting `HttpClient` in a using block will dispose of the object when the code has executed but not close the TCP socket and the TCP state will eventually go to **TIME_WAIT** and stay in that state listing for further activity for 4 minutes (default).

So basically using this multiple times:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //do something with http client
}
```

results in many open TCP connections sitting in **TIME_WAIT**.

You can read the whole thing here:

[You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

So I was wondering what would happen if I did the same with the `ClientBase<TChannel>` derived service class created by Visual Studio when you right-click a project and select add **Add Service Reference . .** and implemented this:

```
    //SomeServiceOutThere inherits from ClientBase
    using (var service = new SomeServiceOutThere()) 
    {
       var serviceRequestParameter = txtInputBox.Text;
       var result = service.BaddaBingMethod(serviceRequestParameter);
       //do some magic (see Fred Brooks quote)
    }
```

However, I haven't been able to recreate exactly the same behavior, and I wonder why.

1. I created a small desktop app and added a reference to a IIS hosted WCF service.
2. Next I added a button that basically calls the code via the using code block like I showed above.
3. After hitting the service the first time, I run netsat for the IP and this is the result:

[image]

4. So far so good. I clicked the button again, and sure enough, new connection established, while the first one went into **TIME_WAIT** state:

[image]

5. However, after this, every time I hit the service it would use the **ESTABLISHED** connection, and not open any more like in the `HttpClient` demo (even when passing different parameters to the service, but keeping the app running).

It seems that WCF is smart enough to realize there is already an established connection to the server, and uses that.

The interesting part is that, when I repeated the process above, but stopped and restarted the application between each call to the service, I did get the same behavior as with `HttpClient`:

[image]

There are some other potential problems with `ClientBase` (e.g. [see here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2014/02/09/a-smarter-wcf-service-client-part-2/)), and I know that temporarily open sockets may not be an issue at all if traffic to the service is relatively low or the server is setup for a large number of maximum connections, but I would still like to be able to reliably test whether this could be a problem or not, and under what conditions (e.g. a running windows service hitting the WCF service vs. a Desktop application).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm surprised by the findings of that blog post. The WebRequest infrastructure normally does connection pooling/reuse with HTTP. Not doing that is a huge perf loss, the TIME_WAIT issue totally aside. This should happen by default.

Comment: Update: I can replicate the HttpClient findings. This is not good.

Answer (score 3):

WCF does not use `HttpClient` internally. WCF probably uses `HttpWebRequest` because that API was available at the time and it's likely a bit faster since `HttpClient` is a wrapper around it.

WCF is meant for high performance use cases so they made sure that HTTP connections are reused. Not reusing connections by default is, in my mind, unacceptable. This is either a bug or a design problem with `HttpClient`.

The 4.6.2 Desktop .NET Framework contains this line in `HttpClienthandler.Dispose`:

```
ServicePointManager.CloseConnectionGroups(this.connectionGroupName);
```

Since this code is not in CoreClr there is no documentation for it. I don't know why this was added. It even has a bug because of `this.connectionGroupName = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);` in the ctor. Two `connectionGroupName`s can clash. This is a terrible way obtaining random numbers that are supposed to be unique.

If you restart the process there is no way to reuse existing connections. That's why you are seeing the old connections in a `TIME_WAIT` state. The two processes are unrelated. For what the code in them (and the OS) knows they are not cooperating in any way. It's also hard to save a TCP connection across process restarts (but possible). No app that I know of does this.

Are you starting processes so often that this might become a problem? Unlikely, but if yes you can apply one of the general workaround such as reducing `TIME_WAIT` duration.

Replicating this is easy: Just start 100k test processes in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Fortunately I am not in a situation that requires me to restart processes, so if WCF handles the Dispose better than HttpClient, there should be no problem. I also tried replicating with a loop as you suggested, and did not experience the HttpClient behavior. Thus I needed to know why it was acting differently (or have someone weigh in on whether I missed something in testing). The use of HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient would explain it.

Comment: Nice overview of WebClient, HttpClient and HttpWebRequest: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/

Comment: What exactly could you not replicate? The broken HttpClient behavior only occurs if frequently disposing it.

Comment: Apologies, could have been clearer: I mean I could not replicate the HttpClient error with whatever WCF was using when I add a service reference  (which, as you pointed out, is likely HttpWebRequest). I basically wanted to see if the same error would come up for other WCF HTTP connections that do not use HttpClient, but did not find the same problem.